# How to calculate torque of a three-phase induction motor?

Tags: control, induction-motor, torque, electric-machine

I have a three-phase induction machine with following nameplate data:

\$V_{s_n}=\frac{425}{\sqrt{3}}\,\mathrm{V}\$ - effective value of the phase voltage,
\$f_n=70\,\mathrm{Hz}\$ - nominal frequency,
\$p_p=3\$ - number of pole pairs,
\$n_m=1383\,\mathrm{rpm}\$ - nominal mechanical speed.

I have also an equivalent circuit for that machine in the following form:

[image]

The parameters of the equivalent circuit are the following:
\$R_S=0.0074\,\Omega\$, \$R_R=0.007548\,\Omega\$, \$R_{fe}=21.277\,\Omega\$, \$L_M=4.265\cdot 10^{-3}\,\mathrm{H}\$,
\$L_L  = 0.231\cdot 10^{-3}\,\mathrm{H}\$.

Let's say I would like to know the nominal torque of the motor. I have started to calculate with the help of the Scilab:

```
// synchronous mechanical speed in (rpm)
nsm = 60*fn/pp;
// nominal slip 
sn = (nsm-nnm)/nsm;

// rotor load resistor corresponding to the nominal slip (Ohm) 
Rload = RR/sn;
// leakage reactance (Ohm)
XL = 2*%pi*fn*LL;
// magnetizing reactance (Ohm)
XM = 2*%pi*fn*LM;

// nodal voltage method for two unknown nodal voltages:
// VM - voltage across the magnetizing branch
// VR - voltage across the rotor resistance
// admitance matrix:
// *diagonal elements are sum of the admitances connected directly to the node
// *off diagonal elements are the negative admitances between the nodes
A = [1/RS + 1/Rfe + 1/(%i*XM) + 1/(%i*XL),              -1/(%i*XL);
                               -1/(%i*XL),   1/(%i*XL) + 1/Rload];
B = [VS/RS; 0];
res = linsolve(A, B);

// phasor of the voltage across the magnetizing branch (rms)
VM = res(1);
// phasor of the voltage across the rotor resistance (rms)
VR = res(2);

// phasor of the rotor current (rms)
IR = (VM - VR)/(%i*XL);
// phasor of the current through the iron losses resistor (rms)
Ife = VM/Rfe;
// phasor of the magnetizing current (rms)
IM = VM/(%i*XM);
// phasor of the no-load current (rms)
I0 = Ife + IM;
// phasor of the stator current (rms)
IS = IR + I0;

// mechanical power in (W)
Pm = 3*Rload*abs(IR)^2;
// synchronous speed (rad/s)
ws = 2*%pi*fn;
// rotor electrical speed (rad/s)
wr = ws - sn*ws;
// rotor mechanical speed (rad/s)
wm = wr/pp;
// mechanical torque in (Nm)
T_01 = Pm/wm;
```

I have got the torque \$1971\,\mathrm{Nm}\$.

Let's say I would like to double check this result via a different approach based on following torque formula: \$T = \frac{3}{2}\cdot p_p\cdot\frac{L_M^2}{L_M+L_L}\cdot i_{s_d}\cdot i_{s_q}\$.

Again with the help of the Scilab:

```
// magnitude of the stator current (rms)
ISmag = abs(IS);
// amplitude of the nominal value of the flux producing component of the stator 
// current (A)
// stator current in no-load condition i.e. s->0
isdn = sqrt(2)*VSn/sqrt(((RS*Rfe)^2 + ((RS+Rfe)*XM)^2)/(Rfe^2+XM^2));
// amplitude of the nominal value of the torque producing component of the
// stator current (A)
isqn = sqrt((sqrt(2)*ISmag)^2 - isdn^2);
// torque in (Nm)
T_02 = 3/2*pp*LM^2/(LL+LM)*isdn*isqn
```

I have got the torque \$2021\,\mathrm{Nm}\$.

My problem is that I have two formulas for the torque calculation whereas both of them are valid in my opinion but each of them provides different value of the motor torque. I have been attempting to find the reason for this discrepancy. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: As an engineer, those two torque figures look identical, especially given the approximations that have to be made when modeling a real physical machine as a mathematical abstraction. If you do want to track down the difference, check each of the assumptions and approximations in each path, and see which are inconsistent.

Comment: This seems kind of contrived. Actual nameplates will have rated power and rated speed. Torque may be listed. If not, the torque can be computed directly from the rated power and speed. For example a 1 HP (746 Watt) motor whose rated speed is 1725 RPM at 208V and 60 Hz will be putting out 746 / (1725 * 2 * pi / 60) = 4.13 Nm. This would be a 4 pole motor with synchronous speed of 1800 RPM at 60 Hz. Slip = 75 RPM / 1800 RPM. Torque will be proportional to slip more or less. If you change the synchronous speed, torque will still be proportional to slip.

Comment: @mkeith thank you very much for your reaction. My actual problem isn't how to calculate the machine torque but my problem is that I have two formulas for the torque calculation and each of them gives different result. I have been attempting to find out why. Can you give me an advice with that?

Comment: I am definitely not enough of an expert to answer. But it looks like the first equation is based on slip torque relationship and the second one is based on torque being proportional to current. So slightly different assumptions in the two models. Probably the second one is more accurate if I had to guess. But IN PRACTICE, if anything is not measured correctly or shifts with temperature (Rs will definitely shift with temperature) then you will get errors of this magnitude easily.

Comment: Compare the policy and explicit assumptions in the two methods. Both are engineering approximations. What factors of one are violated or if ires by the other? This is engineering. 2.5% error - what's not to like ? :-)